# WorkSheet_Change Event does not auto update

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to auto update cell values in Column I based on values in column H.
- I want whenever user enters any value in column H then the first five characters should be copied in corresponding column I.

- if I'm entering 123456789 in column H then 12345 should get auto updated immediately in column I

****Issues faced**

- The values in column i does not get auto populated when values is entered in column H. Suppose there are 5 rows entered in column H the values would only get updated or populated after user enters any value in Column I
- In the below code in the For Loop if i change the Target.Range("B" & i) and when i click on Column , values in column C gets updated and not in B. i understand the expected Target Range mentioned is **column I**, but why does Column C gets updated when i enter Column B in the for loop**

  ```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     If Intersect(Target, Range("I1:I20")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
     Application.EnableEvents = False
     'Set the values to be uppercase
        Dim i As Long
        'With Sheets("Sheet1")
         For i = 1 To 20
             Target.Range("A" & i).Value = Mid(Range("H" & i), 1, 5)

         Next i
        'End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: You are checking for an intersection with I1:I20 which does not square with your description.

Comment: Will check, thanks SJR

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289619

Answer (score 1):

You do not really need to loop - To get the result immediately just simply do this

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H1:H20")) Is Nothing Then

        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Mid(Target.Value, 1, 5)

    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Mid Function Returns a string containing a specified number of characters from a string.